# Grow a div in priority before its sibling

Tags: css, css-position, css-grid, css-float

I have a page that can have two styles depending on users settings:

**Style 1:**

```css
div > div {
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    text-orientation: upright;
}

.left {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  float: left;
}

.right {
  background-color: red;
  float: right;
}

.end {
  background-color: lightblue;
  float: left;
}

.left,
.right,
.end {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="left">LEFT</div>
  <div class="right">RIGHT</div>
  <div class="end">END</div>
</div>
```

**Style 2:**

```css
div > div {
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    text-orientation: upright;
}

.left {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  float: left;
}

.right {
  background-color: red;
  float: right;
}

.end {
  background-color: lightblue;
  float: left;
}

.left,
.right {
  width: 50%;
}

.end {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="left">LEFT</div>
  <div class="right">RIGHT</div>
  <div class="end">END</div>
</div>
```

This works fine, yet it's not as versatile as I wish. For example, I'd like `.left` and `.right` to have dynamic width instead of fix width:

```css
.left,
.right {
  min-width: 40%;
  max-width: 60%;
}
```

and make `.left` grow in priority, i.e.:

- `.left` width is at least 40%
- if `.left` content is larger than 40%, `.left` can grow to take as much as 60%
- `.right` width is at least 40%
- if `.right` content is larger than 40%, it can grow to take as much remaining space as possible (so if `.left` is already taking 60% it cannot grow at all).

Finally, each div height is dynamic and grow according to the div content.

It does not seem to be possible to achieve with CSS `float` (as divs are not aware of each other `width`), but would it be possible to achieve with CSS Grid ?

Comment: Flexbox is probably a better option and using `min-width` and `max-width` on the contents.

Comment: @Paulie_D, yes flexbox would solve the width growing issue, but unfortunately I can't use it because it's not possible to get the style 1 with flexbox...

Comment: CSS-Grid can't help either since Style 1 is not a grid.

Comment: Do you mean that it's impossible to get something similar to the current style 1 with a CSS-Grid ? If that's the case, that would indeed be a showstopper

Comment: Essentially yes. Grid has equal heights across a row and Style 1 does not have that. You *might* be able to do something but with dynamic heights, probably not. You'd have to *know* which column div (Left or right) was going to be tallest.

Comment: Ah I understand better, in this case indeed it won't work as I can't predict which div is going to be the tallest. If you want to post your comment as an answer I'll mark it as accepted, thanks for the explanation

Answer (score -1):

Just slap this into your stylesheet, and you've got a layout that adapts dynamically, giving .left the attention it deserves while keeping everything in harmony.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(40%, 60%) auto;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-orientation: upright;
}

.left {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  grid-column: 1;
}

.right {
  background-color: red;
  grid-column: 2;
}

.end {
  background-color: lightblue;
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">LEFT</div>
  <div class="right">RIGHT</div>
  <div class="end">END</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Answers should contain some explanation, not just instructions to "go use this". See [answer].

Comment: This doesn't seem to address the two layout options.